# Доступ к элементу таблицы через библиотеку d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Пытаюсь получить доступ к элементу таблицы по id, но он стирает все что было в ячейке, а новую информацию не добавляет. Не подскажете, почему?

```
<body>
<table id= tabr border="1">

<tr>
<td id = "one" >row 1, cell 1</td>
<td class = "one1" >row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "one3" >row 2, cell 1</td>
<td class = "one4" >row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
t = [1,2]
table = d3.select("#tabr");
odin = table.select("#one");
odin.data(t).text(function(d) { return d.value; });
 </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде было 2 ошибки:

1. Метод [`.data()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data) предназначен для установки датасета в [выборку](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8), для единичного элемента в d3 есть метод [`.datum()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_datum);
2. Вы обращаетесь к объекту с данными по ключу `.value`, хотя у Вас данные не объект с ключом `value` а массив `[1,2]`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<table id= tabr border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id = "one" >row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td class = "one1" >row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "one3" >row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td class = "one4" >row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  t = [1,2]
  table = d3.select("#tabr");
  odin = table.select("#one");
  odin.datum(t).text(d => d[0] + 'x' + d[1]);
 </script>
```